# Windows 10: login and start local Desktop session remotely

Tags: windows, ssh, command-line-interface, desktop

I have Windows 10 machine with monitor. There is a user with name Admin. It has full Administrators rights.

I can login as Admin locally using password and get the Desktop on the monitor. I can login as Admin via RDP and get Remote Desktop. Also I can login as Admin remotely via SSH and get CLI (PowerShell console for example).

So what I want to get more? I need to start the local Desktop remotely. But not via RDP! I want to do it from CLI.

The scenario: some person sits near the Windows 10 machine and waits. I execute script via SSH/PowerShell, and local Desktop session starts. Person gets Desktop on the monitor.

Is it possible?

Comment: You might have to fake input on the logon screen.